# How to use brace expansnsion in makefile prerequisites?

Tags: bash, makefile, brace-expansion

In bash I can use `src/{foo/{one,two},bar/{three,four}}.o` to describe the files:

```
src/foo/one.o
src/foo/two.o
src/bar/three.o
src/bar/four.o
```

I would like to describe the prerequisites of a makefile target in a similar manner. Is there a way to accomplish this in GNU Make?

This is what I have:

```
SHELL:=/bin/bash

all: src/{foo/{one,two},bar/{three,four}}.o
    @echo "$(^)"
```

And I get:

```
make: *** No rule to make target 'src/{foo/{one,two},bar/{three,four}}.o', needed by 'all'.  Stop.
```

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838278/using-curly-brackets-for-variable-expansion-in-makefile-doesnt-work/12838683#12838683) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681624/how-to-handle-shell-expansions-in-gnu-make-under-ubuntu#6681727) questions that suggest to add `SHELL=/usr/bin/bash` to the makefile. But I still cannot get it to work.

Thanks.

Comment: make uses its own language. It's not shell. Read the documentation for your version to see if there's something that can be used.

Comment: thanks for sending me to read the manual, How didn't I think about that?

Comment: The links you've referenced mention adding `SHELL=/usr/bin/bash` to the makefile, or adding to the OS-level call via `make SHELL=/bin/bash`; in your example you've added an extra `:` between `SHELL` and `=`; can you try removing the `:` from your code and see if that works? obviously verify you've got the right path to your local `bash`, and it wouldn't hurt to verify `bash --version` returns a message that it really is `bash` ... "Duh, Mark!" ?

Comment: @markp-fuso, thanks for the input, I appreciate your time. the bash is effectively in /bin/bash. and := is almost equivalent to =. For this case, there is no difference. Moreover, I came up with an answer to the problem, I just posted in hope somebody else in the future finds it useful.

Comment: so if you remove the `:` it still does not work? and you still have to make the `$(shell ...)` call?

Comment: @markp-fuso, Your approach seems much less cumbersome than mine. However, I just replaced the `:=` for `=` and the behavior is the same. Am I missing something?

Comment: Make does not use the shell to expand prerequisite globbing.  Make uses the standard C runtime functions glob(3).  See the POSIX definition of this here: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/glob.html and you'll see it does not support brace expansion.  If you run the `$(shell ...)` function then make will invoke whatever shell you have set in the `SHELL` variable but that doesn't impact how _make_ expands globbing expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so GNU make has this `shell` command that alone is not much relevant here because the brace expansion is a *bash* thing, and make uses Bourne shell (/bin/sh). But, together with the recommendation of the cited questions, I can do something like this:

```
SHELL:=/bin/bash

all: $(shell echo src/{foo/{one,two},bar/{three,four}}.o)
    @echo "$(^)"
```

With this, the braces are correctly expanded.

Comment: Good answer. While not as succinct as brace notation, if you're going to be using GNU Make anyhow, one can also use the `addprefix` function. For example, `$(addprefix foo, d l t bar)` expands to *food fool foot foobar*.